# Trouble with importing annotations

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm working on a CodeIgniter project in which I'm using Doctrine2 and the Symfony2 Validator component.

All my Doctrine2 entities `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping` and the entity manager recognizes them. My entity annotation looks like this:

```
/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass = "UserRepository")
 * @Table(name = "user")
 * @HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
```

At this point, I'm able to persist entities without any trouble. The first problem arises when I try to use the Symfony2 Validator component. When I try to validate a `User` object, I get this error:

> [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Entity" in class Entity\User was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?

The only "fix" to this issue is through `use Doctrine\Mapping\Entity`, but I have to do that for *every* annotation being used by my entity (Table, Column, ManyToOne, etc.). I'm trying to figure out why I need to explicitely `use` each annotation class instead of them being automatically recognized (shouldn't `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping` grant me access to all the classes within that namespace?).

So, I then tried `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM` and prefacing all my annotations with `ORM\`. Ex: `@ORM\Entity()`. The Symfony2 validator stops complaining, but now Doctrine2 complains that `Class Entity\User is not a valid entity or mapped super class.` I have no idea why this method works for the Validator, but not Doctrine2. If I run the console command `doctrine:orm:info`, my `User` entity is not recognized.

Because this is a CodeIgniter app, I'm autoloading the Symfony2 and Doctrine2 libraries. My autoload code is as follows:

```
# Symfony2 ClassLoader component
require_once __DIR__ . '/application/libraries/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/UniversalClassLoader.php';
$loader = new \Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader();
$loader->register();
$loader->registerNamespace('Symfony', __DIR__ . '/application/libraries/symfony/src');
$loader->registerNamespace('Doctrine', __DIR__ . '/application/libraries/doctrine/lib');

# Doctrine2 
require_once __DIR__ . '/application/libraries/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationRegistry.php';
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(function($class) use ($loader) {
    $loader->loadClass($class);
    $classExists = class_exists($class, false);
    return $classExists;
});
AnnotationRegistry::registerFile(__DIR__ . '/application/libraries/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/DoctrineAnnotations.php');
```

I don't care if I have to preface everything with `ORM\` or not, I just want to find a solution that the Symfony2 Validator and Doctrine2 will both work with. Any ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had a similar issue when using Silex, Doctrine2 and the Symfony-Validator.

The solution was  to avoid using the SimpleAnnotationsReader and instead using the normal AnnotationReader (have a look at [Doctrine\ORM\Configuration::newDefaultAnnotationDriver](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.3/class-Doctrine.ORM.Configuration.html#_newDefaultAnnotationDriver)). You can then preface every entity with `ORM\` (and of course inserting `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;` in every entity).

Comment: What about the case where it worked without `ORM\ ` so we coded every entity that way, now all of a sudden it stops working for no reason and we're left with a maintenance nightmare?

Comment: Just to answer Brandon's question and to save other people the time of finding it out themselves: if your codebase uses Doctrine annotations without importing the `Doctrine\ORM\Mapping` namespace, then you are married to Doctrine's SimpleAnnotationReader, which means you can't _just_ start using namespace-imported annotation and refactor your code incrementally. Well, at least not without hacking the AnnotationReader (which is the one that parses the `use` statements).

Answer (score 14):

I resolved this issue by adding the following to my entity file:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
```

So my file now looks like:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\CustomBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Example
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="example")
 *
 */
class Example
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=125)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     *
     * @return Example
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function gettitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

}
```

Comment: This didn't work for specifically needing the id annotation. I had to specify it individually as @Mostafa's answer was showing.

Comment: My reference was https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance, I just have to add `ORM\` so: 
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE") */
class Person

Answer (score 6):

Add `use` statements for
 every annotation you have used in your `entities`. for example:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Id;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\GeneratedValue;
```

But you may not interesting to use this method. You can write all `use` statements to one file and just include it in your `entities`.

Comment: `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;` lets you use `@ORM\Entity`, etc. which is much more concise. user1825294 has it right.

Comment: This is not the solution you want! Nor what you will have with annotations.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue when php7 got upgraded to php8 during an ubuntu update. I didn't want to update all my project dependencies to php8, so instead I installed ondrej/php ppa and re-installed php7 in addition to php8.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error message "[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Entity" in class Entity\User was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?".

The problem was that I had alias for ORM and did not used it for the annotation.

I had this: `@OneToOne(targetEntity="CompanyProduct")`

And correct was this: `@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="CompanyProduct")`

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing and your tests fail because of this. Make sure you have the right autoload configured in your phpunit settings.

For a very specific scenario, my problem was upgrading my symfony version whereas before i had the `bootstrap.cache.php` file, but on a new version, it is `app/autoload`. I had to change my `phpunit.xml` config file and set my bootstrap option to that file `bootstrap="autoload.php"`

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved by adding:

`use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\HasLifecycleCallbacks;`

Answer (score 0):

### **Ugly solution**

I am learning doctrine and what matters to me at this stage is that I can easily copy/paste examples from the website and use them without additional edits.

- Set the namespace like this for all entities: `namespace Doctrine\ORM\Mapping;`