# How to configure Doctrine Entity Annotation autoloading in User-defined symfony Bundle?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

When I try to validate my symfony schema, I get the error:

```
[Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]                            
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\Orm\Mapping\Entity" in class C  
hill\EmailUser\Entity\EmailUser does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded
```

I see that in this question: [Trouble with importing annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910147/trouble-with-importing-annotations), it is said we need to change from Doctrine Simple Annotation Reader. Even though it seems strange to make bundle config in the autoloader, I tried doing that via app/autoloader.php:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Configuration;

path = __DIR__."/../vendor/path/to/annotationDriver.php"
Configuration::newDefaultAnnotationDriver(path, false);
```

I also tried researching to see if I could find a parameter like:

```
doctrine.orm.mappings.annotations.simple_annotations_reader
```

that I could set to false, but I couldn't find anything.

As you'll see below, I also tried manualling adding mapping for my bundle to the ORM setting in config.yml.

composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "root/photoproject",
"license": "proprietary",
"type": "project",
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "app/AppKernel.php",
        "app/AppCache.php"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "files": [
        "vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php"
    ]
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "doctrine/annotations": "^1.4",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "doctrine/migrations": "^1.5",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3,>=2.3.10",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
    "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~2.7"
},
"scripts": {
    "symfony-scripts": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@symfony-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@symfony-scripts"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin",
    "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": null
}
}
```

app/config/config.yml

```
imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }
- { resource: security.yml }
- { resource: services.yml }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices    /configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
locale: en

    framework:
#esi: ~
#translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }
secret: '%secret%'
router:
    resource: '%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml'
    strict_requirements: ~
form: ~
csrf_protection: ~
validation: { enable_annotations: true }
serializer: { enable_annotations: true }
templating:
    engines: ['twig']
default_locale: '%locale%'
trusted_hosts: ~
trusted_proxies: ~
session:
    # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
    handler_id: ~
fragments: ~
http_method_override: true

    # Twig Configuration
    twig:
debug: '%kernel.debug%'
strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
    # Doctrine Configuration
    doctrine:
dbal:
    driver: pdo_mysql
    host: '%database_host%'
    port: '%database_port%'
    dbname: '%database_name%'
    user: '%database_user%'
    password: '%database_password%'
    charset: UTF8
    # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
    #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
    #     e.g. database_path: '%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3'
    #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
    #   3. Uncomment next line:
    #path: '%database_path%'

orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
    entity_managers:
        default:
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
            auto_mapping: true
            mappings:
                ChillEmailUserBundle: ~

    # Swiftmailer Configuration
    swiftmailer:
transport: '%mailer_transport%'
hostity/l: { type: memory }
```

src/Chill/EmailUserBundle/Entity/EmailUser.php

```
namespace Chill\EmailUser\Entity;

use Doctrine\Orm\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Contraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */

class EmailUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length="1023")
     * @Assert\Email(message="Not a valid email")
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length="4096")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length="4096")
     */
    private $salt;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role")
     */
    private $roles;
}
```

So my question is how can I do what the accepted answer was suggesting in Symfony (while preferably keeping the bundle relatively re-usable).

Thanks

---

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
use Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader;

/** @var ClassLoader $loader */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));
return $loader;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK you have to register loader for `AnnotationRegistry`.

More detailed documentation is [available here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-common/en/latest/reference/annotations.html). In case of symfony project the easiest way is to use `app/autoload` with following contents:

```
<?php

use Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;

/**
 * @var ClassLoader $loader
 */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

return $loader;
```

Because of that need, bundles usually configure container, router, etc. using XML.

If you prefer annotations and that's your private bundle just register loader as I shown above. If you want to make it public, I suggest xmls for config.

Comment: Appreciate the quick reply. I updated my app/autoload.php and tacked that on to the question, but I'm still seeing the error. I think I might just need to switch to XML.

Comment: This is why Doctrine Annotations uses its own autoloading mechanism through a global registry. If you are wondering about the annotation registry being global, there is no other way to solve the architectural problems of autoloading annotation classes in a straightforward fashion. Additionally if you think about PHP autoloading then you recognize it is a global as well."

So I think you're answer is right, "don't". I just need to use XML.

Comment: Are you sure your `bin/console` uses `app/autoload`? And some random ideas: replace `Doctrine\Orm\Mapping` with `Doctrine\ORM\Mapping` (case sensitivity), clear cache (it is possible that your console uses `prod` env and  caches annotations). How do you validate schema?

Comment: Grrr. It was the lowercase Orm after all. Thanks

Comment: Happens, glad you got through that.